# Proof for inequality $1 - \frac{\ln^2n}{n} \ge \left(1 - \frac{\ln n}{n} \right)^{k \ln n}$

Tags: inequality

I would like to prove that

$$ f(n) \ge g_k(n) $$

with

$$f(n) = 1 - \frac{\ln^2n}{n}$$ and $$g_k(n) = \left(1 - \frac{\ln n}{n} \right)^{k \ln n}$$

for $n, k \in \mathbb{R}$ with $n > 1$ and $k > \gamma$ where $\gamma$ seems to be between $1$ and $2$.

It is obvious that at $n = 1$ both sides are equal and numerically the inequality seems to hold for large enough $k$ but I have not been able to come up with a proof.

### Numeric Visualisation

[image: f(n) vs g_k(n)]

Here are some plots of the difference between the left and the right side of the inequality:

$$d_k(n) = f(n) - g_k(n) = 1 - \frac{\ln^2n}{n} - \left(1 - \frac{\ln n}{n} \right)^{k \ln n}$$

for $k = 2$ the inequality seems to hold:

[image: Plot of $d_k(n)$ for $k = 2$]

for $k = 1$ it does not hold:

[image: Plot of $d_k(n)$ for $k = 1$]

for $k = 1.2$ it is a bit strange:

[image: Plot of $d_k(n)$ for $k = 1.2$]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1 - \frac{\ln^2n}{n} \ge \left(1 - \frac{\ln n}{n} \right)^{k \ln n}$$

$$\left( 1 - \frac{\ln^2n}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{\ln^2n}} \ge \left(1 - \frac{\ln n}{n} \right)^{\frac{n}{\ln n}k}$$

let

$$f\left(\frac{n}{\ln^2n}\right)\geq f\left(\frac{n}{\ln n}\right)^k$$

with "f" monotonically increasing

$$f(x)=(1-\frac1x)^x \leq \frac1e$$

thus

$$\ln \left[ f\left(\frac{n}{\ln^2n}\right)\right]\geq k\ln \left[ f\left(\frac{n}{\ln n}\right)\right]$$

that is

> $$k \geq MAX\left(\frac{\ln \left[ f\left(\frac{n}{\ln^2n}\right)\right]}{\ln \left[ f\left(\frac{n}{\ln n}\right)\right]}\right)= M\approx 1.25447$$

[image]

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(ln((1-log%5E2x%2Fx)%5E(x%2Fln%5E2x))%2Fln((1-lnx%2Fx)%5E(x%2Flnx)))+x%3D1..250

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=local+max+(ln((1-log%5E2x%2Fx)%5E(x%2Fln%5E2x))%2Fln((1-lnx%2Fx)%5E(x%2Flnx)))

**NOTE**

the existence of MAX is guarantee by **Weierstrass Theorem** since:

- for $n=e$ the ratio is $1$
- for $n=2e$ the ratio is $>1 $
- for $n\to +\infty$ the ratio $\to 1$

Comment: Simplifying the problem by matching the exponent with the inner part was a good idea. This is already better than what I have come up with. Unfortunately, the final step still relies on numerical magic such as WolframAlpha. Do you have an idea that would help me prove that the fraction inside of the $MAX$ has a global maximum?

Comment: You could use Weirstrass theorem to show that it admits Max.

Comment: Doesn't that only help me on bounded intervals?

Comment: You could show that for n=e the ratio is 1 for $n=2e$ is $> 1$ and for $n\to +infty$ the ratio $\to 1$. Isn't it sufficient?

Comment: @MaximilianKöstler what about the last hint? do you agree with this way to prove?

Comment: I agree that this should be sufficient. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome Max, it was a nice question. Bye